# Script hangs only when started via SystemD

Tags: apache-kafka, systemd, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to start the Kafka Connect component alongside Cloudera and want to wrap the Kafka Connect startup script in a `systemd` service file such that it can start on boot once the Cloudera services start.

For some strange reason if I start this script outside of `systemd` it works just fine, but when I start it via `systemctl start kafka-connect` it just hangs at the following log entry lines.

```
[Unit]
Description=Kafka Connect - Distributed
After=network.target cloudera-scm-agent

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/app/cloudera/parcels/KAFKA/lib/kafka/bin/connect-distributed.sh -daemon /app/cloudera/kafka-connect/connect-distributed.properties"
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
2019-07-18 13:40:27,962 INFO  (main) [ConnectDistributed(main:69)] Scanning for plugin classes. This might take a moment ...
2019-07-18 13:40:27,992 INFO  (main) [DelegatingClassLoader(registerPlugin:184)] Loading plugin from: /app/cloudera/kafka-connect/plugins/splunk-kafka-connect.jar
2019-07-18 13:40:27,993 DEBUG (main) [DelegatingClassLoader(registerPlugin:191)] Loading plugin urls: [file:/app/cloudera/kafka-connect/plugins/splunk-kafka-connect.jar]
2019-07-18 13:40:29,206 DEBUG (main) [VersionUtils(getVersionFromProperties:63)] found git version string=v1.1.0 in version.properties file
2019-07-18 13:40:29,219 INFO  (main) [DelegatingClassLoader(scanUrlsAndAddPlugins:207)] Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/app/cloudera/kafka-connect/plugins/splunk-kafka-connect.jar}
2019-07-18 13:40:29,220 INFO  (main) [DelegatingClassLoader(addPlugins:136)] Added plugin 'com.splunk.kafka.connect.SplunkSinkConnector'
2019-07-18 13:40:29,220 INFO  (main) [DelegatingClassLoader(addPlugins:136)] Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter'
```

My next thought was to try something a bit simpler and just create an `init.d` script at `/etc/init.d/kafka-connect` which works fine because it is nothing more than a shell script wrapper **UNTIL** I source in the `/etc/init.d/functions` file which causes this to be started via `systemd` again.

Two main questions -

1. What does `systemctl` do differently than a regular shell script that would cause this shell script (which in turn launches a java process) to hang at that exact same step everytime.
2. If my `/etc/init.d/kafka-connect` script works, is it okay to use on RHEL7? If so, is there a way to load that `init.d` script on boot of the server?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try removing `-daemon` flag and change `Type=simple` from `forking`, see if it helps

Comment: Hi @TarunLalwani - I have tried both of these with no luck. Removing the `-daemon` flag does not help. Also according to all documentation online given my research it should be `Type=forking` due to the fact that it spawns another process and systemd needs to be okay with the parent process existing.

Comment: Try using `ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "env && /app/cloudera/parcels/KAFKA/lib/kafka/bin/connect-distributed.sh -daemon /app/cloudera/kafka-connect/connect-distributed.properties"` and do the same in your `init` file which works and see if any environment variable is different between the two

Comment: @TarunLalwani the only ENV variable different was the `PATH` variable which I set in the `Environment=` field in my `systemd` Unit file and restarted and I still see the same behavior as the process just hangs again executing `systemctl restart kafka-connect` command.

Comment: How about adding a sleep, does it help?

Comment: Hi @TarunLalwani, I tried changing the ExecStart to `ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "env && sleep 10 && /app/bds/parcels/KAFKA/lib/kafka/bin/connect-distributed.sh -daemon /app/bds/elm/kafka-connect/connect-distributed.properties"` and it still hangs.